# How to add an app to Facebook business page (favorites)

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I'm trying to add my Facebook app (iframe integration) to a Facebook business page. But can't figure out the rifht way to do it, because Business accounts can use apps. Looked through all Facebook Docs&Help and found nothing. (

Will be grateful for any clue.

Thanks

Comment: If you are the admin of the app and admin of the page, just copy and paste this url www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=URL_WITHIN_YOUR_DOMAIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to configure the Pages Tab options (last one on the Apps Basic Settings page). Check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/ for instructions. Let me know if that was what you're looking for :)

Comment: Thank you, asifrc! Your answer gave me a hint how to do it. First one have to configure Page Tabs option as you wrote. Second step is to go to link https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL Then your App will be attached your business page on Facebook.